# Datagridview Boolean Value is always true

Tags: c#

I have a datagridview that is importing data from an SQLite db.
I have a method that i want to retrieve all the values from the currently selected datagrid row with the use of a class/object.
I have it mostly working except for one field (selectedRecord.complete) which happens to be a boolean.
For some reason it is always returning back as true regardless of the data that is in the datagrid view.
I have checked that it is looking at the right row index etc and it appears to be.
To add to the confusion I have another boolean value (selectedRecord.structCalc) and that seems to work fine using the same code i have been trying so far.

Any ideas where i am going wrong?

This is where i set up my class

```
public class SelectedRecord
{
public string enquiryIDString;
public string clientString;
public string contractManagerString;
public string receivedDateString;
public string requiredDateString;
public string completeDateString;
public string descriptionString;
public string actionString;
public string designerString;
public string desEstHoursString;
public string engineerString;
public string engEstHoursString;
public bool structCalc;
public bool complete;
}

  SelectedRecord selectedRecord = new SelectedRecord();
```

This is wheere the values are set

```
 int rowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
selectedRecord.enquiryIDString = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
selectedRecord.clientString = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].Value);
selectedRecord.contractManagerString = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].Value);
selectedRecord.receivedDateString = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value);
selectedRecord.requiredDateString = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].Value);

selectedRecord.completeDateString = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].Value);

selectedRecord.descriptionString = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].Value);
selectedRecord.actionString = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].Value);
selectedRecord.designerString = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[8].Value);
selectedRecord.desEstHoursString = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[9].Value);
selectedRecord.engineerString = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[10].Value);
selectedRecord.engEstHoursString = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[11].Value);
selectedRecord.structCalc = Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[12].Value); 
selectedRecord.complete = Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[13].Value);

                MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(selectedRecord.complete));
```

The message box is just for testing to see what value is returning and it always come back as "true"

```
public void RefreshGrid()
        {
            //Public method to refresh the grid

            SQLiteConnection dbConnectionString;
            dbConnectionString = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source = F:\Omega\Drawing Register\DRDB.sqlite; Version = 3");
            dbConnectionString.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Jobs";
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, dbConnectionString);
            var sqlDataAdapt = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, dbConnectionString);
            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
            {
                sqlDataAdapt.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

                //Set Font
                dataGridView1.Font = new Font("MS Sans Serif", 8);
                //Set Column Widths
                dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 100;
                //Set Column Names
                dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Enq No";
            }

        }
```

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Jobs (
  jEnquiryNumber VARCHAR(40),
  jReceivedDate DATE,
  jRequiredDate DATE,
  jCompleteDate DATE,
  jClient VARCHAR(40),
  jContractManager VARCHAR(40),
  jDescription VARCHAR(60),
  jAction VARCHAR(20),
  jDesigner VARCHAR(40),
  jDesignEstHr NUMERIC,
  jEngineer VARCHAR(40),
  jEngineeringEstHr NUMERIC,
  jStructuralCalc BOOLEAN)
```

Comment: Please always be considerate of the people you're asking to volunteer their time to help. You have created a situation where we all need to scroll your code horizontally for no good reason. You have removed the leading whitespace from the first line but not the rest so the indenting is inconsistent. Both bad and both lazy. You can remove the useless whitespace from all lines when you copy it or after you paste it, making it easy and comfortable for us to read your code when we spend our time helping you.

Comment: As for the problem. if `selectedRecord.complete` is always `true` then whatever is in `dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[13].Value` always converts to `true`. What else could we tell you, given what little we know? We don't even know what the actual value is. You need to provide a much more detailed explanation of the problem if you want us to be able to help. You might start by reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and updating your question accordingly.

Comment: Its not a case of being lazy, more not realising it was an issue. Now that i know i have fixed it (it was just how it pasted in from my editor)
I am new to this and dont necessarily know what is required and how to format it.
My code is pages long so I was trying to make it brief so that you had less to read through. I will look to see what else it relevant and try and update

Comment: By the way, why do `int rowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;` and `dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells` when you can do `var row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;` and `row.Cells`?

Comment: I didnt think of that do be honest. Im still learning and so there are probably shorter ways of doing things than i am. I will make that amendment

Comment: It is difficult to visualize what columns are in the grid. It appears the class `SelectedRecord.RowIndex` field is NOT displayed in the grid? This `RowIndex` field is never getting set in the second code snippet, so I question its purpose. How is the grid filled with data? AND are ALL fields from the `SelectedRecord` Class being displayed?

Comment: Without more info on how the code fills the grid… You may want to note, that if the code used a List/BindingList of `SelectedRecord` objects, then used that list as a `DataSource` to the grid, then you could get any rows `SelectedRecord` object with something like… `selectedRecord = (SelectedRecord)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;` … this should simply things.

Comment: @JohnG, Thank you for the reply. I have added the code to the above to show how the datagrid view is populated.
Regarding the selectedRecord.RowIndex, that is somethng I edded in early on that was mainly for testing whe i was just trying to identify which row index was being returned. I can remove that from the code

Comment: Now I am confused. If the grid gets the data from the DB, and it appears to be a `DataTable`, then, what purpose does the `SelectedRecord` Class have? I mean in the second code snippet, it clearly is “creating” a new `SelectedRecord` object, but what is the code doing with the object afterwards? Also, the code to fill the grid isn’t help much, we need to see what the `DataTable` columns look like and you do not show this. Is what I am getting at is that the code “appears” sound and should work… so I am betting the index is wrong… but I can not confirm this unless we see the `DataTable` schema.

Comment: Sorry if my explination is not good, as i have mentioned im new to this and im not sure what is relevant and how to explain it well. I appreciate your time looking at it though.

So the general idea is this:
I have an SQLlite DB with a load of records in it.
I want to display all of the records from one of the tables in said db in the datagrid view.
The user is to click on which ever record they are interested on in the datagridview which will then show said record elsewhere on the form but then also allow them to edit it and update it back to the db.

Comment: As the data in the datgridview is filled from a data adapter I have used the SelectedRecord object to identify which record is selected and then populate the other ara of the form that i mentioned.
Like I say, it is working as expected except for that one field.

Comment: The table in the database was created using the below SQL:
```
CREATE TABLE Jobs (jEnquiryNumber VARCHAR(40), jReceivedDate DATE, jRequiredDate DATE, jCompleteDate DATE, jClient VARCHAR(40), jContractManager VARCHAR(40), jDescription VARCHAR(60), jAction VARCHAR(20),jDesigner VARCHAR(40), jDesignEstHr NUMERIC, jEngineer VARCHAR(40), jEngineeringEstHr NUMERIC, jStructuralCalc BOOLEAN)
```

Comment: You should [edit] your question to add your last comment as part of your original question. Some may not read the comments and the code is definitely needed in your question. Also, as far I can see there is NO column in the table that corresponds to field number 13… `selectedRecord.complete = Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[13].Value);` … ? … the table schema you posted does not have a “Complete” field so it is a guess as to where column 13 in the grid comes from.